# Hibernate saving self Reference parent/child

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4 and MySQL. I have a self referencing class called Lecturers which has annotations implementing a parent/child one to many relationship. I have a problem with implementing a controller and form for saving a parent and child from the same table. It's a self-referencing class.

My DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `lecturers` (
`lecturer_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`checker_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`lecturer_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`checker_id`) REFERENCES `lecturers` (`lecturer_id`)
```

The Java class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
private Lecturer checker;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Lecturer> lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
```

And the class also has this method

```
@Transient
public void addLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
    if(lecturers == null) {
        lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
        //lecturers = new HashSet<Lecturer>();
    }
    lecturer.setChecker(this);
    lecturer.setLecturers(lecturers);
    //lecturer.setLecturers(lecturers);

    lecturers.add(lecturer);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I then set up a DAO and Service layer for implementing a CRUD operations. The create method is this:

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

// Create new lecturers
    Lecturer lecturer1 = new Lecturer();
    lecturer1.setName(name);
    lecturer1.setEmail(email);

    Lecturer lecturer2 = new Lecturer();
    lecturer2.setName(name);
    lecturer2.setEmail(email);

       // Create new checker
    Lecturer checker = new Lecturer();
    checker.setName(name);
    checker.setEmail(email);
    checker.setChecker(checker);


    List<Lecturer> lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
    lecturers.add(lecturer1);
    lecturers.add(lecturer2);
    lecturer1.setChecker(checker);
    lecturer2.setChecker(checker);

    checker.addLecturer(lecturer1);
    checker.addLecturer(lecturer2);

    checker.setLecturers(lecturers);

  session.save(checker);


    session.save(lecturer1);
    session.save(lecturer2);
```

My requirement is now to provide a form that will be used to match a parent (Checker) to one or more children (Lecturers) and save the match to the database. I'm asking how I should go about saving the relationship. Should I create the parent and children separately, then match a parent using the id to a children selected from say a drop down list? I'm not sure how to make sure the relationship between a checker and its respective lecturers is saved.

I then created a main class for testing the relationship and to see if it works. Inserting data into the db works but when I want to list it I get this:

```
Name: Mark
Email: ma@msn.com
Checker: com.professional.project.domain.Lecturer@439942
ID: 22
```

I should get the name of the checker back which I already added but it's not coming back.

I would appreciate some help on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your addLecturer() method has a bug. It shouldn't set the lecturers list of the child to the current lecturer's list:

```
public void addLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
    if (lecturers == null) {
        lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>(); // OK : lazy initialization
    }
    lecturer.setChecker(this); // OK : set the parent of the child to this
    lecturer.setLecturers(lecturers); // this line should be removed : the child's children shouldn't be the same as this lecturer's children

    lecturers.add(lecturer); // OK : ad the child to the list of children
}
```

When you get a lecturer, you obtain the following as the checker :

```
Checker: com.professional.project.domain.Lecturer@439942
```

The above is just the result of the call to the default `toString()` method on the checker. To get its name, call `getName()` on the checker. If you want the toString() method to return the name, then implement it that way:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the toString() method, it does return the name now. I have made some changes to the addLecturer method. Could you please clarify on the lazy initialization part - is there a better way I can initialize it? And if I can ask, is there a way I can implement it in the controller and form for saving?

Comment: In fact, since the list is eagerly initialized in at construction time (`private List<Lecturer> lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();`), checking for null is unnecessary. Just keep the two last lines of the method.