# Spring Roo self relationship as parent (OneToMany) and child (ManyToOne)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I have the following domain, which not saves the parent ID.

```
privileged aspect Item_Roo_DbManaged {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idItemParent")
private Set<Item> Item.items;    //item children

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IdItemParent", referencedColumnName = "IdItem", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Item Item.idItemParent;    //item parent
```

What I do is:

```
1- To create a List with the Item objects and save each one (just to get the item ID first, for insert/update). 
2- Assign the parent ID to each child item.  -- I tried saving this first without success
3- Assign to each parent its child list  -- I tried saving this first without success
4- Update each item in database. -- I tried this first saving each item without success.
```

*Note:* Each ID is being generated n the process.

**The problem** is, that the parent ID of each Item child is null, the parent ID is not being saved.

Here the process receiving the steps 1 and processing steps 2, 3 and 4:

```
    private List<Item> setItemsParent(List<Item> itemList) {
    Map<Long, Item> parents= new HashMap<Long, Item>();
    LinkedList<Item> newItemList= new LinkedList<Item>();

    Iterator<Item> it= itemList.iterator();
    Set<Item> children= null;

    while ( it.hasNext() ) {
        Item item= it.next();
        Long key= item.getHierarchyNbr().longValue() - 1l;
        Item parent= parents.get(key);          

        if (parent != null) {
            children= parent.getItems() == null? new LinkedHashSet<Item>() :parent.getItems();
            children.add(item);
            parent.setItems(children);
            itemRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);

log.debug("PARENTi:" + parent.toString());
        }

        item.setIdItemParent(parent);
        itemRepository.saveAndFlush(item);
        parents.put(item.getHierarchyNbr(), item);

log.debug("CHILDi:" + item.toString());

        newItemList.add(item);

log.debug("NewListi:" + newItemList.toString());

        it.remove();
    }

    return newItemList;
```

The log displays which is correct:

```
651  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10192; hierarchyNbr:0; Desc:item1; ParentId: null]
664  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10192; hierarchyNbr:0; Desc:item1; ParentId: null]
681  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10193; hierarchyNbr:1; Desc:item2; ParentId: 10192:item1]
688  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10193; hierarchyNbr:1; Desc:item2; ParentId: 10192:item1]
695  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10194; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item3; ParentId: 10193:item2]
711  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10194; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item3; ParentId: 10193:item2]
717  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10195; hierarchyNbr:3; Desc:item4; ParentId: 10194:item3]
731  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10194; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item3; ParentId: 10193:item2]
739  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10196; hierarchyNbr:3; Desc:item5; ParentId: 10194:item3]
747  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10194; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item3; ParentId: 10193:item2]
753  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10197; hierarchyNbr:3; Desc:item6; ParentId: 10194:item3]
757  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10192; hierarchyNbr:0; Desc:item1; ParentId: null]
764  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10198; hierarchyNbr:1; Desc:item2.1; ParentId: 10192:item1]
773  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10198; hierarchyNbr:1; Desc:item2.1; ParentId: 10192:item1]
777  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10199; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item2.1.1; ParentId: 10198:item2.1]
785  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10198; hierarchyNbr:1; Desc:item2.1; ParentId: 10192:item1]
801  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10200; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item2.1.2; ParentId: 10198:item2.1]
804  - PARENTi:Item [ItemId:10198; hierarchyNbr:1; Desc:item2.1; ParentId: 10192:item1]
808  - CHILDi:Item [ItemId:10201; hierarchyNbr:2; Desc:item2.1.3; ParentId: 10198:item2.1]
```

I followed the clues below without success:

[Adding a one to many relationship to a self reference parent/child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184580/adding-a-one-to-many-relationship-to-a-self-reference-parent-child)

[Hibernate saving self Reference parent/child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121456/hibernate-saving-self-reference-parent-child)

[JPA: How to have one-to-many relation of the same Entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    dbo.Item
    (CreateTs, CreateUser, Descr, ForAnyCompanyInd, IdIndustry, IdUom, IsClassifiedInd, IsParentInd, LastUpdateTs, LastUpdateUser) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

As you can see, in the query there is not any reference to **IdItemParen** field for insert/update, so, what alternatives do I have? or what's wrong with the code above if the inserts/updates are in both sides "parent/child".

Folks, I figured it how this works, Roo added (insertable = false, updatable = false) parameters by default, I had to change them to TRUE, so the filed can be available for insert/update and is working fine now. Most of the tips don't have those parameters, so, that is the reason that those worked fine and my bad because I didn't release that from beginning.